# Why does Rust's u64.pow expect a u32?

Tags: types, rust, integer, integer-arithmetic

Why is it that Rust's `u64` primitive expects a `u32` exponent?

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/protagonists.rs:13:25
   |
13 |         return root.pow(self.secret) % prime;
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected u32, found u64
help: you can convert an `u64` to `u32` and panic if the converted value wouldn't fit
```

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u64.html#pow.v

Comment: Consider that for values that are not 0 or 1, the biggest possible non-overflowing exponent is 63.

Comment: Thanks, that was my assumption too, it just kinda makes the code messy (but that's better than getting runtime errors obviously.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Why do most operations require operands of the same type?

It's easy for *us* to see that `2i32 + 2i64` should be `4i64`, but to a CPU, `2i32` and `2i64` are completely different and totally unrelated things. `+` inside a CPU is really just a piece of hardware that typically supports two 32-bit inputs or two 64-bit inputs, but not one 32-bit input and one 64-bit input. So in order to add an `i32` to an `i64`, the shorter number has to be sign-extended to 64 bits before both values can be plugged in to the ALU.

The same is generally true for most integer and floating-point arithmetic operations: A conversion has to be done to do math on mismatched types. In C, the compiler usually promotes both operands to the smallest type that can represent both values; these implicit conversions are called the ["integer promotions" or "usual arithmetic conversions"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20747614/3650362) depending on context. In Rust, however, the compiler mostly only knows about same-type operations, so you have to choose what kind of operation you want by deciding how to convert the operands. People who like Rust generally consider this to be a good thing.¹

## Why doesn't this apply to `u64::pow`?

Not all arithmetic operations, even those implemented in hardware, accept arguments of the same type. In hardware (although not in LLVM), shift instructions often ignore the higher bits of the shift argument (this is why in C shifting by more than the size of the integer invokes undefined behavior). LLVM offers [`powi` instructions](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#llvm-powi-intrinsic) that raise a floating-point number to an integer power.

These operations are different because the inputs are asymmetric, and designers often take advantage of these asymmetries to make hardware faster and smaller. In the case of `u64::pow`, though, it's *not* implemented with a hardware instruction: [it's just written in plain Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/num/mod.rs.html#3669-3689). Bearing that in mind, it's clear that requiring the exponent to be a `u64` is quite unnecessary: As [Schwern's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57120020/3650362) points out, `u32` is more than capable of containing all the possible powers that a `u64` could be raised to with any hope of accuracy, so the extra 32 bits would be just pointless.

## OK, why `u32`?

The last sentence is equally true of `u16` or even `u8` -- a `u64` can't contain `pow(2, 255)`, so using `u32` seems nearly as wasteful. However, there are also practical considerations. Many calling conventions pass function arguments in registers, so on a 32-bit (or larger) platform you will not see any advantage from going smaller than that. Many CPUs also do not support native 8-bit or 16-bit arithmetic, so the argument would have to be sign-extended anyway to implement the exponentiation-by-squaring algorithm I linked to earlier. In short, I don't know specifically why `u32` was chosen, but things like this may have factored into the decision.

---

¹ C's rules are somewhat encumbered by history and supporting a wide range of historical hardware. Rust only targets LLVM, so the compiler doesn't need to worry about whether the underlying hardware has a primitive 8-bit `add` instruction or not; it just emits `add` and lets LLVM worry about whether it will be compiled to a primitive instruction or emulated with 32-bit ones. This is why `char` + `char` is `int` in C, but `i8` + `i8` is `i8` in Rust.

Answer (score 8):

This is an educated guess.

Consider that a u64 raised to a u32 is already more than capable of overflowing any u64. For example, if we take 2 (the smallest possible significant u64) and raise it to merely 2^10 or 1024 we get something rather larger than a u64.

> 179769313486231590772930519078902473361797697894230657273430081157732675805500963132708477322407536021120113879871393357658789768814416622492847430639474124377767893424865485276302219601246094119453082952085005768838150682342462881473913110540827237163350510684586298239947245938479716304835356329624224137216

There's no point in allowing an even larger exponent, it just means a more expensive calculation that is more likely to overflow.

If a u64 cannot safely be downgraded to a u32, it *definitely* cannot safely be used as an exponent. [u128.pow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u128.html#method.pow) also only takes a u32 exponent for the same reason.

Note: there is [overflowing_pow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u64.html#method.overflowing_pow) to detect a likely overflow.

Comment: If that is the reason, why isn't it `u8` instead of `u32`?

Comment: @PeterHall [trentcl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57120777/14660) has a theory. I'll add my own. In low level languages like Rust integer overflow is occasionally a desirable thing, like for a hashing function. Limiting exponentiation to `u8` would take that away. [Rust's design wrt overflow has evolved over time](https://huonw.github.io/blog/2016/04/myths-and-legends-about-integer-overflow-in-rust/), and they [appear to have settled on explicit "wrapping" operators](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0560-integer-overflow.md).