# How to efficiently convert a number n to an integer with that many bits set? eg 8 -> 0b11111111?

Tags: rust

How do you *efficiently* convert a number *n* to a number with that many low significant bits set? That is, for an 8-bit integer:

```
0 -> 00000000
1 -> 00000001
2 -> 00000011
3 -> 00000111
4 -> 00001111
5 -> 00011111
6 -> 00111111
7 -> 01111111
8 -> 11111111
```

Seems trivial:

```rust
fn conv(n: u8) -> u8 { (1 << n) - 1 }
```

But it's not:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to shift left with overflow', src/main.rs:2:5
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=861652f973e0376cfbff99e8398fb0a1)

This is because, in Rust, a number with N bits cannot be shifted left N places. It is undefined behaviour on many architectures.

`u8::MAX >> (8 - n)` doesn't work either as shift right has the same overflow restriction.

So, what is an efficient way to achieve this without a lookup table or a conditional? Or is this not possible and one must resort to an implementation like:

```rust
fn conv2(n: u8) -> u8 {
    match 1u8.checked_shl(n.into()) {
        Some(n) => n - 1,
        None => u8::MAX,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The most efficient way, for any bit width smaller than the largest native integer size, will almost certainly be to use a wider type for calculations and then narrow it to the output type:

```
pub fn conv(n: u8) -> u8 {
    ((1u32 << n) - 1) as u8
}
```

[rustc 1.50 at `-C opt-level=1` or higher](https://godbolt.org/z/ovjYYq) renders this as four instructions with no branches or indirection, which is probably optimal for x86-64.

```
example::conv:
        mov     ecx, edi
        mov     eax, 1
        shl     eax, cl
        add     al, -1
        ret
```

On most (all?) 32-bit or larger platforms, there's no advantage to be gained from doing math with `u8` or `u16` instead of `u32`; if you have to use a 32-bit register you may as well use the whole thing (which is also why [certain integer methods only accept `u32`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57119562/3650362)).

Even if you write a `match`, it may not be compiled to a branch. In my tests, the following function

```
pub fn conv(n: u32) -> u64 {
    match 1u64.checked_shl(n) {
        Some(n) => n - 1,
        _ => !0,
    }
}
```

compiles with no branches, just a `cmov` instruction, and looks [pretty similar](https://godbolt.org/z/vPW7o3) to the equivalent using (software-emulated) `u128`. Be sure to profile before assuming that the `match` is a problem.

Comment: You are right, this is most likely faster than the table lookup for everything up to a 32-bit parameter. And for 64-bit the compiler does something shifty with the 128-bit arithmetic: https://godbolt.org/z/K68q76

Comment: Hmm, that's pretty similar to the `match` version, actually.